# Distribution of identical things into distinct groups vs identical groups

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose some n identical balls have to be given to 5 people A,B,C,D,E such that everyone gets at least one ball.

My question is how would this particular case differ from a case where we are considering the groups as identical and not distinct groups/people like above.

I think the formula for the 1st case is (n-1)C4 but what of the second case?

I am finding this very difficult to understand this intuitively, so any help would be thoroughly appreciated

Comment: The difference is already visible with $2$ "bins". If they are not distinguishable, then there are $3$ ways to divide $7$ identical objects into $2$ bins, at least $1$ in each. These could be called $\{1,6\}$, $\{2,5\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. If the bins are distinguishable, there are $6$ ways.

Comment: Thank u sir, but is there some separate formula for identical groups?

Comment: For dividing $n$ objects into $k$ (non-zero) parts, the number is uusually called something like $P(n,k)$. It counts certain special **partitions** of $n$. There are useful recurrences for $P(n,k)$, but no nice closed form formula like the one for distinguishable groups.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where people are distinguishable, give one ball to each to make sure each has at least one, then find the number of functions from a set with $n-5$ elements to a set with $ 5$ elements. Each  function is an assignment of objects to the $5$  distinguishable people.